# Handling space between images in ReactNative Drawer Menu

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using `'@react-navigation/drawer'` to show the left side drawer menu. I'm attaching the screen shot here with.
[image]

The issue is that, between the top image and the actual menu, there's a gap that I'm not able to customise/reduce.
Also, the gap on the icon and logout text at the bottom of the screen shot is also not customisable.
Here's my code for top image and menu in the drawer. At the bottom of the code, look at  for logout option.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
 <Image
  source={{ uri: BASE_PATH + proileImage }}
  style={{resizeMode: 'center', width: 100, height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100 / 2, alignSelf: 'center',}}
 />
 <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
  <DrawerItemList {...props} labelStyle={{fontFamily: Fonts.regular, fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '700', color: '#37383C'}} />
 </DrawerContentScrollView>
 <DrawerItem labelStyle={styles.menuLabel}
  icon={({ focused, color, size }) => <Icon type='MaterialCommunityIcons' name={'logout'}        color={color} />}
  label="Logout"
  onPress={logout}
 />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

     //Use this hook
     const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

     //Use this as an style

     contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingTop: insets.top,
        paddingStart: insets.left,
        paddingEnd: insets.right,
      }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).